# Perturbation of the principal eigenvector of a PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, perturbation-theory, positive-definite

> **Setting:** I have a $n \times n$ PSD matrix $A$ and $\tilde{A}=A+E$ be its symmetric perturbation such that $\|E\|_2=\epsilon.$ Let
>   $(\lambda,u)$ be the principal eigenvalue, eigenvector pair of $A$ and
>   $(\tilde{\lambda},\tilde{u})$ be that for $\tilde{A}$ (the eigenvalues
>   are unique).

**Objective:** I am trying to get a tight bound for the perturbation of principal eigenvector $\|u-\tilde{u}\|_2.$

**Attempts:** Using the reference [Stewart and Sun 1990] used in this paper by Ng et al. ([ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/ijcai01-linkanalysis.pdf](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/ijcai01-linkanalysis.pdf)) I can get a $O(\sqrt{n}\epsilon)$ bound (however I am unable to access the reference book). I also have a simpler proof which gives $O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$ bound.

> **Question:** Any idea how to get a tighter (possibly $O(\epsilon)$) bound? or a condition on the error magnitude ($\epsilon \leq \delta$ )
>   when the overall perturbation will also be $O(\epsilon).$ Any
>   reference note/book/papers will be helpful too.

Comment: Why don't you work with 2 by 2 matrices to find examples attaining the bounds cited? Then you'll know if a tighter bound exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about it. The problem is in worst case the bound can be even $O(1)$ when the perturbation is $\epsilon=O(\delta)$ where $\delta=\lambda-\lambda_2$ the eigengap between first and second eigenvalues. In the best case the perturbation is of course $0,$ when it is along the same direction as $u.$ I am sure I can find examples where the bound is achieved. The theorem is valid when $\|E\|_F<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}.$  I guess what I really want is a condition when the bound can be $O(\epsilon).$ Or a reference which points to some state of the art bounds

Comment: I remember we did some norm stuff in our Numerical Analysis course. There, it was convenient with $<.,.>_A$ norm, when A is SPD. In this norm, more can be said about $A$ and its eigenvalues. For instance, the maximum over unitary vectors of this norm is exactly equal to the biggest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Yes. But I don't see how to use that here.